# Interpretation of dissipation (instead of emission) of an external density current volume - Electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I came to this question when simulating volume currents in COMSOL (a FEM solver) at a certain frequency *w*.

We can define in 2D  an volumetric electric current $J_e (x,y)$ in units of $A/m^2$. This current will induce electromagnetic fields in the space around it and in the space occupied by the volumetric electric current. The permittivity of all the space is $\epsilon=1$ (*i.e.* vacuum).

By defining a surface that encloses $J_e(x,y)$ we can calculate the Poynting vector, integrate it over the surface, multiply it by the normal to the surface and obtain the energy emitted by the current source.

Now, we can compute the integral of $1/2  \int Real(E J^*) dV$  in the volume, and due to Poynting theorem, it will be equal to minus the exiting energy. $E$ is the total field since there are no other sources in the problem.

However, in most of the calculation certain sections of the volume current, the quantity $1/2Real(E J^*) $  is positive (albeit on average is negative, indicating that the volumetric current is radiating overall). This is due to the fact that **the total electric field have a direction which is mostly opposite to the external current in some regions**.

This happens for many different volume current distributions.

Hence, the first interpretation I did was that some external currents are not *radiating*, but *absorbing*, which I find extremely puzzling.

I've checked some books, Jackson & Balanis to find some physical interpretation, but I failed to do so.

So I came here to ask:

1. Does it make sense to define the integral of  $Real(EJ^*)$, where **E**
   is the field created only by external sources, and compute it at the position of the sources?
2. How do you interpret the fact that $Real(EJ^*)$ is positive in the position of a source? (Is it absorbing instead of radiating?)

PD: This question arised since I am trying to simulate 2nd harmonic generation in metals, where you can use the hydrodynamic model to identify different current sources in the second harmonic.

Comment: Wouldn't the units of $J$ in 2D be $\mathrm{A/m}$, not $\mathrm{A/m}^2$?

Comment: More to the point of your question, where does the electric field come from?  Is the current distribution time-dependent ($J_e(x,y,t)$)?  If it's not, then I would have thought that the electric field would be zero, since static current distributions don't create electric fields.  Perhaps there are some details you're assuming that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Hi! The units are indeed A/m^2, and are defined in an area (a 2D "volume") which is "arbitrary". In the initial case I encountered was defined in a ring surrounding a metal, but it happens even when it is defined in vacuum.

The current density $J_e(x,y)$ is the only electric field source in the system. It is oscillating periodically with frequency $\omega$, since I am solving it in the frequency domain